# Linking error for multiplication declaration of static data member

Tags: header-files, linker-errors

I am getting linking error for multiple declaration of a static data member. I took all the necessary precaution to avoid multiple inclusion of the header file but still I am getting error.

```
//dummymessage.h
#ifndef DUMMY_MESSAGE
#define DUMMY_MESSAGE

#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string"

class CDummyMessage
    {
    private:
        static int CDummyMessage::ObjCount1;
    public:

        CDummyMessage(void);
        CDummyMessage(std::string content, int type);
        ~CDummyMessage(void);
    private:
        std::string m_Message_content;
        int m_type;
};

    int CDummyMessage::ObjCount1 = 0;
#endif
```

//dummymessage.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "DummyMessage.h"

using namespace dummy;
CDummyMessage::CDummyMessage(void)
{
std::cout<<"Constructor called. ID: "<<++CDummyMessage::ObjCount1<<std::endl;
}


CDummyMessage::~CDummyMessage(void)
{
std::cout<<"Destructor called. ID: "<<--CDummyMessage::ObjCount1<<std::endl;
}
CDummyMessage::CDummyMessage(std::string content, int type):
m_Message_content(content)
{
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "list"
#include "process.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "DummyMessage.h"


using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
for(auto i = 0;++i < 10000;){
        CDummyMessage* l_pNewMsg = new CDummyMessage("Test message", i);
        g_Message_queue.push_front(l_pNewMsg);
    }    return 0;

}
```

I am getting linking error for this:-

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "private: static int dummy::CDummyMessage::ObjCount1" (?ObjCount1@CDummyMessage@dummy@@0HA) already defined in DummyMessage.obj  C:\Users\Veil\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SmartPointerExample\SmartPointerExample\SmartPointerExample.obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `CDummyMessage::ObjCount1` definition to a source file.

Header guards only protect your headers from being included more than once in the same translation unit; they don't prevent them from being included by different translation units.

Currently, each translation unit that includes your `dummymessage.h` header is defining `CDummyMessage::ObjCount1`. When the compiler tries to link all of your code together, it sees that multiple object files contain definitions for `CDummyMessage::ObjCount1`.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot Dauphic for your reply. I still have some confusion. Can you please elaborate your sentences with respect to the code I have written,"Header guards only protect your headers from being included once in the same translation unit; they don't prevent them from being included by different translation units."
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a typo; header guards only protect your headers from being included __more than once__ in the same translation unit. Each .cpp file you compile is a translation unit, and can include your `dummymessage.h` once. Each .cpp file that includes it gets it's own definition of `CDummyMessage::ObjCount1`, so when the linker tries to link them together, it doesn't know which to use.

Comment: your suggestion worked for me and now with your explanation its clear to me as well..Thanks.

Comment: One more doubt came to my mind. If you don't initialize any global or static members it is expected to do self initialization...so if I am skipping this line, int CDummyMessage::ObjCount1 = 0;...I am still getting this error.. does that mean if this line is not there compiler implicitly add this line to the file where its declared?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you don't define it with `int CDummyMessage::ObjCount1` anywhere, then you should get an unresolved symbol error, instead of an already defined error.

Comment: what behavior will you expect if you don't write that definition at all..?